# Reversal badge: After 5 down-votes, does an up-vote negate the reversal potential?

Tags: discussion, reversal-badge

I answered a question that had 5 down-votes. It was the first time I have even seen a question with that many down-votes and that has not been closed. Furthermore, it seemed to me a [legitimate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512693/initiate-sp-databases-for-a-c-listbox/6524989#6524989); maybe it was a little rough on the English, but answerable.

It was eligible for the reversal badge due to having 5 down-votes (in the unlikely event I get 20+ votes).

My question is:  if someone comes along and votes it up; is the badge  no longer eligible (since it's now above 5)? Or, is the question score when I first answered enough?

Comment: Nice... only four more down votes to go and ChrisF can get a reversal !!!!  But ??? is this not the forum for such questions?

Comment: Ironically, your own comment `5 downvotes?? harsh` might have triggered a sympathy upvote.

Comment: Ha, that's funny, just noticed that as well.  Like I said... the likelyhood was pretty low that my answer would ever make it to 20 - it's not like it was ground-breaking stuff.  Just made me curious.  I guess I can give an up-vote to his question myself now.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question has to have a score of -5 when your answer reaches a score of +20.

So if it gains *any* upvotes in the time it takes your answer to reach +20, then you won't get the Reversal badge.

Comment: Ok, that's why it's a gold then... that seems unlikely to happen.  Thanks.

Comment: @lazyDBA - well for one thing a question at -5 won't get many views so you're potential for getting views on your answer is lowered. Also a +20 answer is a **good** answer while a -5 question is a **very bad** question and the chances of providing such an answer are quite small.

Comment: Five downvotes or a score of negative 5?

Comment: @jcolebrand - score of -5